# SQL Query Performance Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a hierarchy like following
Group
Company
Department
Cost Centre
Which are being stored in database like following table structure.

Table Name : **OrgHierarchy**
Columns : **Id, ParentId, Level, Type**

In My Employee View I have employee **Cost Centre, Department, Company** and **Group** present.

I need help in writing better performing query to find employee for a particular node in the hierarchy (it can be Group/Company/Department/Cost Centre)

```
  Select * from vw_Employee  emp
    Where emp.CostCentreId = @NodeId 
    OR emp.DepartmentId=@NodeId 
    OR emp.CompanyId=@NodeId 
    OR emp.GroupId= @NodeId
```

Here the number of “OR” statement making the query very slow.

Is there any better approach to handle the efficiently or any other approach?

Comment: Please post the view code too

Comment: You can always find the hints of the performance using actual execution plan

Comment: View have nothing.. its just same as table

Comment: `Select * from vw_Employee  emp WHERE emp.CostCentreId = @NodeId
UNION
Select * from vw_Employee  emp WHERE emp.DepartmentId=@NodeId 
UNION
Select * from vw_Employee  emp WHERE emp.CompanyId=@NodeId
UNION
Select * from vw_Employee  emp WHERE emp.GroupId= @NodeId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `OR` in condition makes indexis be skipped. Replace it with `UNION`:

```
Select * 
from vw_Employee  emp
Where emp.CostCentreId = @NodeId 
UNION
Select * 
from vw_Employee  emp
Where emp.DepartmentId=@NodeId 
UNION
Select * 
from vw_Employee  emp
Where emp.CompanyId=@NodeId 
UNION
Select * 
from vw_Employee  emp
Where emp.GroupId= @NodeId
```

[Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72726/index-seek-much-slower-with-or-condition-compared-with-separate-selects) is a good question.

Comment: I think you should use `UNION` instead

Comment: @CodeMonster hi, can you accept this answer or I should improve it?